# plotting data points on waves from dynamically generated data using d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

i have plotted dynamic waves based on randomly generated data in d3.js. I am using "dot" (svg.selectAll("dot")) element to represent the data point(x and y axis) on the waves. Based on setinterval method my data is getting updated every 200ms and i am transforming the data from right to left. But the data points(dots) that i added to the waves are not moving along with the waves, they are fixed(not moving) and only waves are moving.

here's the code: 
https://jsfiddle.net/rajatmehta/tm5166e1/4/

```
function updateData() {

    var newData = GenData(N,lastUpdateTime);
    lastUpdateTime = newData[newData.length-1].timestamp;

    var newData2 = GenData2(N,lastUpdateTimeNew);
    lastUpdateTimeNew = newData2[newData2.length-1].timestamp;

    for (var i=0; i<newData.length; i++){
    console.log(globalData.length);
        if(globalData.length>99){
        globalData.shift();
        }
        globalData.push(newData[i]);
    }
    for (var i=0; i<newData2.length; i++){
    console.log(globalDataNew.length);
        if(globalDataNew.length>99){
        globalDataNew.shift();
        }
        globalDataNew.push(newData2[i]);
    }

        //code for transition start
        x1 = newData[0].timestamp;
        x2 = newData[newData.length - 1].timestamp;
        dx = dx + (x(x1) - x(x2)); // dx needs to be cummulative

        x1New = newData2[0].timestamp;
        x2New = newData2[newData2.length - 1].timestamp;
        dxNew = dxNew + (x(x1New) - x(x2New)); // dx needs to be cummulative


        d3.select("path#path1")
            .datum(globalData)
            .attr("class", "line")
            .attr("d", valueline(globalData))
            .transition()
            .ease("linear")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + String(dx) + ")");




        d3.select("path#path2")
            .datum(globalDataNew)
            .attr("class", "line")
            .attr("d", valueline2(globalDataNew))
            .transition()
            .ease("linear")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + String(dxNew) + ")");



    svg.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
}
```

I am new to d3.js, so dont have much idea about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems:

1. You are not appending the circles correctly: you **cannot** append a `<circle>` element to a `<path>`element. You have to use an "enter" selection, appending them to the SVG (or a group element):

   ```
   chartBody.selectAll(null)
       .data(globalData)
       .enter()
       .append("circle")
       .attr("class", "dot1")
       .attr("r", 3)
       .attr("cx", function(d) {
           console.log(d)
           return x(d.timestamp);
       })
       .attr("cy", function(d) {
           return y(d.value);
       });
   ```
2. In the update function, select those circles by **class**:

   ```
   d3.selectAll(".dot1")
       .data(globalData)
       .transition()
       .ease("linear")
       .attr("transform", "translate(" + String(dx) + ")");
   ```

Here is your code with those changes:

```js
var lastUpdateTime = +new Date();
var lastUpdateTimeNew = +new Date();

var GenData = function(N, lastTime) {
  var output = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    output.push({
      value: Math.random() * 10,
      timestamp: lastTime
    });
    lastTime = lastTime + 1000;
  }

  return output;

}
var GenData2 = function(N, lastTime) {
  var output = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    output.push({
      value: Math.random() * 20,
      timestamp: lastTime
    });
    lastTime = lastTime + 1000;
  }

  return output;

}
var globalData;
var globalDataNew;

// plot the original data by retrieving everything from time 0
data = GenData(50, lastUpdateTime);
dataNew = GenData2(50, lastUpdateTimeNew);

lastUpdateTime = data[data.length - 1].timestamp;
lastUpdateTimeNew = dataNew[dataNew.length - 1].timestamp;

globalData = data;
globalDataNew = dataNew;

// Define the div for the tooltip
var div = d3.select("body").append("div")
  .attr("class", "tooltip")
  .style("opacity", 0);

var margin = {
    top: 30,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 50
  },
  width = 800 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 350 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.time.scale()
  .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .range([height, 0]);


x.domain(d3.extent(globalDataNew, function(d) {
  return d.timestamp;
}));
y.domain(d3.extent(globalDataNew, function(d) {
  return d.value;
}));


var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
  .orient("bottom")
  .ticks(d3.time.seconds, 20)
  .tickFormat(d3.time.format('%X'))
  .tickSize(5)
  .tickPadding(8);

var xAxisTop = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
  .orient("bottom").tickFormat("").tickSize(0);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
  .orient("left").ticks(5);

var yAxisRight = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
  .orient("right").tickFormat("").tickSize(0);

var valueline = d3.svg.line()
  .x(function(d) {
    return x(d.timestamp);
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return y(d.value);
  });

var valueline2 = d3.svg.line()
  .x(function(d) {
    return x(d.timestamp);
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return y(d.value);
  });

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


svg.append("rect")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .attr("class", "plot");

var clip = svg.append("clipPath")
  .attr("id", "clip")
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", 0)
  .attr("y", 0)
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

var chartBody = svg.append("g")
  .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");



/* .on("mouseover", function(d) {  
            div.transition()  
                .duration(200)  
                .style("opacity", .9);  
            div .html(formatTime(d.timestamp) + "<br/>"  + d.close) 
                .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")  
                .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px"); 
            })     
        .on("mouseout", function(d) {  
            div.transition()  
                .duration(500)  
                .style("opacity", 0); 
        })*/


chartBody.append("path") // Add the valueline path
  .datum(globalData)
  .attr("id", "path1")
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr("d", valueline);

chartBody.selectAll(null)
  .data(globalData)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("class", "dot1")
  .attr("r", 3)
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return x(d.timestamp);
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return y(d.value);
  });

chartBody.selectAll(null)
  .data(globalDataNew)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("class", "dot2")
  .attr("r", 3)
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return x(d.timestamp);
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return y(d.value);
  });





chartBody.append("path") // Add the valueline path
  .datum(globalDataNew)
  .attr("id", "path2")
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr("d", valueline2);


svg.append("g") // Add the X Axis
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g") // Add the Y Axis
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + width + ",0)")
  .call(yAxisRight);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + String(0) + ")")
  .call(xAxisTop);

svg.append("text")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr("y", 0 - margin.left)
  .attr("x", (0 - (height / 2)))
  .attr("dy", "1em")
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .style("font-weight", "bold")
  .text("Return (%)");


var inter = setInterval(function() {
  updateData();
}, 1000);





//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var N = 3;
var dx = 0;
var dxNew = 0;

function updateData() {

  var newData = GenData(N, lastUpdateTime);
  lastUpdateTime = newData[newData.length - 1].timestamp;

  var newData2 = GenData2(N, lastUpdateTimeNew);
  lastUpdateTimeNew = newData2[newData2.length - 1].timestamp;

  for (var i = 0; i < newData.length; i++) {
    if (globalData.length > 99) {
      globalData.shift();
    }
    globalData.push(newData[i]);
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < newData2.length; i++) {
    if (globalDataNew.length > 99) {
      globalDataNew.shift();
    }
    globalDataNew.push(newData2[i]);
  }

  //code for transition start
  x1 = newData[0].timestamp;
  x2 = newData[newData.length - 1].timestamp;
  dx = dx + (x(x1) - x(x2)); // dx needs to be cummulative

  x1New = newData2[0].timestamp;
  x2New = newData2[newData2.length - 1].timestamp;
  dxNew = dxNew + (x(x1New) - x(x2New)); // dx needs to be cummulative


  d3.select("path#path1")
    .datum(globalData)
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", valueline(globalData))
    .transition()
    .ease("linear")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + String(dx) + ")");

  d3.select("path#path2")
    .datum(globalDataNew)
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", valueline2(globalDataNew))
    .transition()
    .ease("linear")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + String(dxNew) + ")");

  d3.selectAll(".dot1")
    .data(globalData)
    .transition()
    .ease("linear")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + String(dx) + ")");

  d3.selectAll(".dot2")
    .data(globalDataNew)
    .transition()
    .ease("linear")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + String(dx) + ")");

  svg.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
}
```

```css
body {
   font: 12px Arial;
 }
 
 path {
   stroke: black;
   stroke-width: 1;
   fill: none;
 }
 
 .axis path,
 .axis line {
   fill: none;
   stroke: black;
   stroke-width: 2;
   shape-rendering: crispEdges;
 }
 
 text {
   fill: black;
 }
 
 rect {
   fill: #add8e6;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```

PS: You have to append new circles as the lines move to the left. However, this is **another** issue.

Comment: thanks a lot gerardo. this much part is working fine.

but i also need to append circles as the lines move to the left, which is not happening right now.

how to do that ?

Comment: As I said this is another issue, so please post another question (with the new code, of course).

Comment: i have asked another ques for that too,
you can find it here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46034414/how-to-move-circlesdata-points-in-d3-js